# Shall we add some background color for the code block in the deleted answers too?

Tags: feature-request, design, deleted-answers, code-block

The code block in the deleted answer are not have any grey background color. The code block looks like normal text. Example [deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339315/312043) (10k+ users)

Shall we add some background color for the code block in the deleted answers too?

Current UI:

[image: Current UI]

Expected UI:

[image: Expected UI]

Comment: Very good idea, I'm surprised this hasn't been suggested before.